# Script Will Not Load - No Errors in Firebug

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to create a flipbook using jQuery Booklet plugin. I am following a tutorial that can be found [here](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/12/14/moleskine-notebook/). The page just says loading and nothing happens after that.

[Here is a jsFiddle I created.](http://jsfiddle.net/Lynda333/eMdVA/1/)

Here is my code:

***HTML***

```
<div class="book_wrapper">
  <a id="next_page_button"></a>
  <a id="prev_page_button"></a>
  <div id="loading" class="loading">Loading...</div>
  <div id="mybook" style="display:none;">
    <div class="b-load">

      <div>
        <h2>Pen N Hand's Artwork </h2>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="images/artwork/img.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

***JS***

```
$(function() {
  var $mybook       = $('#mybook');
  var $bttn_next        = $('#next_page_button');
  var $bttn_prev        = $('#prev_page_button');
  var $loading      = $('#loading');
  var $mybook_images    = $mybook.find('img');
  var cnt_images        = $mybook_images.length;
  var loaded            = 0;
  //preload all the images in the book,
  //and then call the booklet plugin

  $mybook_images.each(function(){
    var $img    = $(this);
    var source  = $img.attr('src');
    $('<img/>').load(function(){
      ++loaded;
      if(loaded == cnt_images){
        $loading.hide();
        $bttn_next.show();
        $bttn_prev.show();
        $mybook.show().booklet({
         //Booklet Options
        });
      }
    }).attr('src',source);
  });

});
```

I see no errors in Firebug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I see no errors in Firebug.

I do:

[image]

So make sure you have specified an url to an image that actually exists.

Comment: I agree with @Darin Dimitrov . I also got the same error when trying js fiddle.

Comment: I wonder why I did not see the same errors. That was it, thanks.